# What does the term 10GA CT-PT means for a CT-PT wiring?

Tags: mains, panel-mounting

We have a MCC in our garage of commercial outlet facility. The bucket with the metering unit needs to be configured with the GE-PQM 2 (Power Quality Meter),and CTs and PTs are required to provide the signal to current and voltage inputs to the meter respectively. However, the specification for the bucket mentions, "the CT & PT wiring should be 10 GA". What does the term GA means ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauge.

It describes the wire sizing in AWG (American Wire Gauge) or kcmils (kilo-circular mils).

A 10-GA wire has a conductor diameter of ~2.6mm and a cross sectional area of ~5.3mm².

Comment: That is quite large cable given that the secondaries of CTs are typically 1A or 5A nominal and 10AWG is rated for approx 30A, if not more. We usually use 1.5mm^2 in metric-land.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica Yes it indeed seems to be a huge for current value of 1 A or 5 A, however the specification mentions these words verbatim, "CT & PT wiring should be 10 GA unless stated otherwise on drawings", this means should the secondary circuit should have 10 AWG ?